# Is it possible to load constrains from file (csv, txt) to Deequ Checks?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, amazon-deequ

Is it possible to save suggested constrains to file and then load them as cheks? I was able to do it without saving them with next code

```
val allConstraints = suggestionResult.constraintSuggestions.flatMap {
      case (_, suggestions) =>
        suggestions.map {
          _.constraint
        }
    }.toSeq

val generatedCheck = Check(CheckLevel.Error, "generated constraints", allConstraints)

val verificationResult: VerificationResult = {
        VerificationSuite()
          .onData(tested_df)
          .addCheck(generatedCheck)
          .run()
      }
```

However I want to save them to file and apply them later when needed? Is there any way to do this?